# How to modify java play i18n lang in play framework 2.4.x?

Tags: java, playframework, internationalization

I'm working on a java play framework 2.4.x project.

I have this code in my application.conf file:

```
play.i18n.langs = [ "en-US", "th-TH"]
```

Before i am using the code below in play framework 1.2.x

```
application.langs = us_en,th_th
```

What I want is to make it work in play framework 2.4.x if the langs are in this format "**us_en, th_th**".

I think I need to have a controller for that to make it work, but I don't know how to. Appreciate your help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of migration, you can write the code that will work with the old cookies and fix them as well, so after some time you will remove that migration code.

The example is

```
class HomeController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport{
  lazy val langCookieName = messagesApi.langCookieName
  lazy val defaultLang = "en-US"

  def index = Action { request => {
    // Read the cookie
    val langCookie = request.cookies.get(langCookieName)

    // Detect the old cookie
    if(langCookie.contains("_")){

      // Fix it, "us_en,th_th"  =>  "en-us", "th-th"
      val langCookieFixed = langCookie.map(_.value.replace("_", "-")).getOrElse(defaultLang)

      // implicit here to put language in the context, so template take it in the current request
      implicit val lang = Lang(langCookieFixed)

      // Draw request and change the cookie to fixed version
      Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready.")).withLang(lang)
    }else{
      Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
  }}
```

In the case is you plan always receive the old format, better to write the action composition:

```
class HomeController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) 
  extends Controller with I18nSupport with Play1Actions {

  def index = Play1LanguageAction { request => {
     Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }}
}

// Trait here is for injection of MessagesApi
trait Play1Actions {

  // We need MessagesApi for getting language cookie name
  def messagesApi: MessagesApi

  lazy val langCookieName = messagesApi.langCookieName
  lazy val defaultLang = "en-US"

  // Action composition
  object Play1LanguageAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {

      // Override request with the new, fixed acceprted languages
      val play1Request = new WrappedRequest[A](request) {

        // Read the cookie
        val langCookie = request.cookies.get(langCookieName)

        // Fix it, "us_en,th_th"  =>  "en-us", "th-th"
        val langCookieFixed = langCookie.map(_.value.replace("_", "-")).getOrElse(defaultLang)
        val lang = Lang(langCookieFixed)

        // Override default accepted languages
        override lazy val acceptLanguages = Seq(lang)
      }

      // Do the next action with the owerrided request
      block(play1Request)
    }
  }
}
```

You can also rewrite i18n module, so it will work with "us_en,th_th" "natively", but it is much more work. Here is the original implementation:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.5.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n